# What occurred when all the Trollocs fell to the ground screaming?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *The Eye of the World*, the first book in the Wheel of Time cycle, the following occurs:

> And in that moment the pulling vanished. The Trolloc at his leg threw up its hands and screamed. All of the Trollocs screamed, a howl like all the dogs of the world gone mad.

> Around the humans all the Trollocs fell writhing to the ground, tearing at their hair, clawing their own faces. All of the Trollocs. Biting the ground, snapping at nothing, howling, howling, howling.

What was the 'pulling' and why did all the Trollocs fall to ground 'howling' like dogs?

@Rand al'Thor: I didn't take note of the chapter.

Comment: Isnt that when the Myrddraal was killed

Comment: Can you provide a more exact citation, e.g. chapter number or what happens just before/after this? Context is key.

Answer (score 7):

### The Myrddraal that linked them was killed by Lan.

> Above roar and howl crashed the tolling of the Warder's sword against the Myrddraal's; the air flared blue around them, flared again. Again.

> Then Rand saw the Myrddraal. Still upright in the saddle of its madly dancing horse, black sword still flailing, it had no head.
>
>  <sub>*The Wheel of Time* - *The Eye of the World*, Chapter 18, The Caemlyn Road</sub>

Throughout the earlier books it has been established that Myrddraal can link with the minds of bands of Trollocs. It's also described explicitly in *The Wheel of Time Companion* (and *The World of Robert Jordan's The Wheel of Time*)

> Myrddraal can also link with the minds of a band of Trollocs, overriding their bestial nature and taking control of their minds and wills to create a deadly, well-disciplined fighting force almost as effective as was originally intended. Unfortunately, the Myrddraal was then the weak link. **If it was killed, the Trollocs sharing the link died with it.**
>
>  <sub>*The Wheel of Time Companion* - M, Myrddraal (P.514)</sub>

---

**"What was the 'pulling'?"**

> A Trolloc dashed in and seized Rand's leg, forcing his foot free of the stirrup.

A Trolloc attempting to pull Rand off his horse.